# i have two properties Datetime ExpirationDate and Ulong Duration how to add both values

Tags: c#, type-conversion, datetime-format

`ExpirationTime = DateTime.Now + Duration`
I want to add datetime with `ulong` I have check some type casting examples in google it did not help much could someone please guide me how can I achieve this without hardcoded values?

My datetime format is like this format `2023-09-08T19:29:00Z`

Duration is in DDD:hh:mm format

Comment: "my datetime format is like this format" - that's irrelevant for DateTime. A DateTime doesn't have a format. What's rather more important is what your ulong value is meant to represent. A number of seconds? Microseconds? Milliseconds? Minutes? Hours? That's the first thing you need to know.

Comment: Take a look at the methods on [`DateTime` here from the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-7.0#methods) - namely those methods starting with "Add..."

Comment: TimeSpan t = new TimeSpan(days, hours, minutes, 0);
            return (ulong)t.TotalSeconds;

Comment: Jon Skeet
 sir my duration representing totalseconds

Answer (score 0):

A date and a duration has no display format. They are just data that is presented to you according to the `Culture` of the thread.

Therefore, in C# you can do

```cs
var duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(x);
var expirationTime = DateTime.Now + duration
```

The real question is: what do your `ulong` represent? Is it the duration in seconds, if so use `FromSeconds(x)`, is it the duration in ticks? If so, use `FromTicks((long)x)` and so on.

When you have your date, it is your responsibility to format it, this is best detailed at [Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings).